# Exclude types from sampling in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have seen other posts about this but it doesn't seems to work for me.

I have added the ExcludedTypes to my ApplicationInsights.config.

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>499</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  <MaxSamplingPercentage>10.0</MaxSamplingPercentage>
  <MinSamplingPercentage>1.0</MinSamplingPercentage>
  <ExcludedTypes>Exception</ExcludedTypes>
</Add>
```

I have added a custom page with a generated exception that do a "TrackException" but nothing happens.

```
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic.Add("Title", "MyTestException");

            (new TelemetryClient()).TrackException(ex, dic);
```

I see the error in the "Live Metric Stream" but nothing in the new "Failures" or in the "Search". Am i missing something or what?

Comment: Let's understand whether exceptions are not being logged at all or that exceptions are being sampled out. Do you see any failures? Or is it the only one app logs? Did you test it on high volume app? Or did you test it on low volume app (where sampling has no effect)?

Comment: odd.  if you see it in livemetrics, you should eventually also see it in your real data.